# Mi código de JavaScript solo se ejecuta una vez al hacer click en un div

Tags: javascript

Estoy haciendo que con un `div` se abra una especie de menú cambiando simplemente la propiedad `CSS` `transform` del mismo.

El asunto es que mi código solo se ejecuta una vez y por lo tanto el **menú no se "Cierra", si no que solo se abre**.

Espero haberme explicado. Aquí les dejo el código que he utilizado.

**Js:**

```
function callMenu () {

    var b;
    var i = document.getElementById("menu");

    if (b == 1) {

        document.getElementById("title").textContent = b;
        i.style.transform = "translateX(0%)";
        b = 0;

    } else {

        i.style.transform = "translateX(-100%)";
        b = 1;
        document.getElementById("title").textContent = b;
    }

}
```

**Html:**

```
<div class="container" onclick="callMenu()">
     <div class="bar1"></div>
     <div class="bar2"></div>
     <div class="bar3"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: El HTML no incluye un elemento con id "menu" ni id "title" pero los llamas en tu función, deberías incluirlos para cumplir con las pautas de [mcve].

Answer (score 2):

Estas usando una variable **local a la función**. El valor de `b` **se pierde** cada vez, por lo que no es que solo se ejecute una vez, es que **siempre hace lo mismo**.

Una posible solución: convierte la variable en **global**:

```
function callMenu( ) {
  var i = document.getElementById( "menu" );

  if( b == 1 ) {
  ...
```

Por supuesto, asegúrate de que no la usas en ningún otro sitio, o, mejor aún, cámbiale el nombre por otro mas *descriptivo*:

```
function callMenu( ) {
  var i = document.getElementById( "menu" );

  if( MenuYaMostrado == 1 ) {
  ...
```

Personalmente, me gusta *cualificar* por completo las variables globales. Toda variable global pertenece al objeto `window`, así que yo haría

```
function callMenu( ) {
  var i = document.getElementById( "menu" );

  if( window.MenuYaMostrado == 1 ) {
  ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Eso es debido a que tienes la variable `b` dentro de tu función y por eso cada vez que llamas se reinicia en `var b;` ponla fuera de tu función y veras como funciona, usa también para hacer un debug de tu código, el  [console.log()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Console/log) para monitorear como lo hice en tu código:

```
var b;
function callMenu(){
console.log ("Valor de b: " + b);
    var i = document.getElementById("menu");
    if(b == 1)
       {
           document.getElementById("title").textContent = b;
           i.style.transform = "translateX(0%)";
           b = 0;
       }else{

           i.style.transform = "translateX(-100%)";
           b = 1;
           document.getElementById("title").textContent = b;
       }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Al ejecutar la funcion siempre la variable b se inicializa. Por ende no se guarda el ultimo valor que se le asigno. Es decir siempre va a ser 0 cuando se ejecute la funcion y solo ejecutara abrir. Debes hacer que la variable sea global. Es decir que sea independiendte de la funcion. Tambien para evitar usar una variable puedes poner cono condicion que cumpla o no con una propiedad css. En jquery por ejemplo seria:
 if($(elemento).css(“display”) == “none”){
       //quiere decir que esta cerrado
}else{
      // quiere decir que esta abierto
}